# Trying to make an object jump using tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```py
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(window, width=1280, height=720)
canvas.pack()
a = (0, 50), (50, 100) # coordinates of the rectangle
rect = canvas.create_rectangle(a, fill="red")
#rect = canvas.create_oval(a, fill="red")
speed = 5 # speed of the rectangle
jump = False
    
def keypress(event):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    if event.char == "a": x-= speed
    elif event.char == "d": x+= speed
    elif event.char == "w": y-= speed
    elif event.char == "s": y+= speed
    elif event.char == " ":
        y = 50
        jump = True
        while jump:
            y = 0
            jump = False
    canvas.move(rect, x, y)
    canvas.update()
    canvas.after(1)

window.bind("<Key>", keypress)
window.mainloop()
```

This is my code, im trying to make the rectangle jump but whenever i add the jump code, everything stops working even the normal "asdw" movement that would work otherwise

Comment: Actually you want to have speed in the x and the y directions. Each frame you should add the x coordinate to the x speed and the y coordinate to the y speed. When you want to jump you want to increase the y speed by a constant and then each frame decrease the y speed unless it's touching the ground.

Comment: Also why do you have `canvas.after(1)` and `canvas.update()`? They are useless. Also also `canvas.move(rect, x, y)` moves in the x direction by `x` pixels what you need is `canvas.moveto(rect, x, y)` so it moves to the x coordinate

Comment: error, canvas object has no attribute moveto

Comment: What is the rectangle supposed to do when you jump? The program works fine (even after jumping) but if the spacebar is pressed, `y` is just left at the value `0` via an unnecessarily complicated route and nothing at all happens. How do you want the rectangle to move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you just want to do a simple jumping animation where the rectangle goes up and down again, just use physics: Define a gravitational pull and an initial vertical velocity and then loop until the ground is reached again:

```
    elif event.char == " ":
        diff = 0  ## Difference to initial level
        y = -3    ## Initial speed in y direction
        grav = .1 ## Gravitation
        while diff >= 0:  ## While it is still jumping (higher than initially)
            canvas.move(rect, x, y)
            canvas.update()
            sleep(.01)    ## Pause for 1/100 second
            diff-=y       ## Update current jumping height
            y+=grav       ## Update the speed in y direction
        y = 0 ## Just so it is not moved again, afterwards
```

To make this code snippet work, you have to import time.sleep at the beginning of the program:

```
from time import sleep
```

Comment: The rectangle just moves up very slowly,

Comment: Did you, by chance, miss the `.` in `sleep(.01)`? Then, it moves up very slowly for about half a minute before descending.